# HTML Frameset: Frameset Open in new tab/window

Tags: html, css, frameset

I was thinking this since last week how to solve my problem using the frameset.

***Scenario:***

I have a html file for *header, footer, menu, and content* with there own background color. I used the frameset for better design.

Background color of my *header* is black, for *footer* is also black, *menu* is gray and *content* just plain white.

Everything works perfectly but I saw a problem in *menu*, when the user click the home page using the **Open Link in New Tab** or **Open Link in New Window** the design for home page is just only white.

***Question:***

Is there a way that when the user click the link using **Open Link in New Tab** or **Open Link in New Window** the background color of the four html file will also included?

Here's my code for frameset:

```
<frameset rows="120,*,30" border ="0">
<frame name ="top" src="header.php">

</frame>

<frameset cols="200,*" border ="0">
<frame src="menu_viewer.php" name="menu">
<frame src="index.php" name="main" scrolling="yes">
</frame>
</frameset>

<frame name="bottom" src="footer.php">

</frameset>
```

***Here's a printscreen of my design:***

[image]

And when the user click **Open Link in New Tab** or **Open Link in New Window** ***the result is***

[image]

***The correct result should be:***

[image]

Any suggestions or recommend program as long as the result of the design is like that is also welcome. Advance thank you.

Comment: Wow, framesets. Haven't seen those in last 10 years. Sure you want to use such an outmoded and frowned upon technique?

Comment: @deceze..Actually... I tried to revised it using css, but my problem with using the css is when the user open it in a big screen or different screen resolution the design is collapse..So I decided to used frameset but thats my problem in frameset :(

Comment: That's absolutely not CSS' fault but yours. CSS designs can be made to work on any screen size and are in fact very easy to even *optimize* for different sizes. That's a bad reason to choose framesets, really.

Answer (score 0):

@ Princess Toledo: framesets are now not supported in HTML5. and if u do it in css then use a wrapper to your code i.e.

```
<body>
<div id=wrapper>
<!-- your code -->
</div>
</body>
```

and give css to wrapper as

```
#wrapper {
  width:980px;
  margin: auto;
 }
```

this wil keep your content fit inside the `wrapper` and at center of the page and wil not collapse in high resolution window.

Comment: @vishalkin.... My footer.html is a fixed position... how can I auto it that the footer should be in before the end of the content...?